# install theme to style wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to figure out how to install this theme to style my wordpress admin.

Does anyone know where in the root to install these files?

http://themeforest.net/item/avenxo-responsive-angularjs-html-admin/11660185

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are two ways of making a WordPress Admin themee: with a Plugin or by simply changing the CSS. 
In this case, it recomended to make a new plugin because Angular Js needs more file js to works fine. Then this file js must be included in the core of wordpress.

Here is an example to init and activate a new plugin in wordpress:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Admin Theme
Plugin URI: http://example.com/my-crazy-admin-theme
Description: My WordPress Admin Theme - Upload and Activate.
Author: Ms. WordPress
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://example.com
 */

function my_admin_theme_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style('my-admin-theme', plugins_url('wp-admin.css',  __FILE__));
 }
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_theme_style');

?>
```

I hope this help,
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to give a look at [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes). Note the answer by @Stefano Tux points you to the right direction.

Hope this helps